# Обновление списка в MainActivity, после закрытия другого активити

Tags: android, база-данных, listview, cursoradaper

Есть ListView, который отображается с данными в MainAcitvity. Данные он получает через БД. Также имеется и второе активити, для добавления данных в БД. Логика приложения такова, что после добавления данных в базу второе активити уничтожается и мы вновь возвращаемся на MainActivity. Но новые данные не отображаются. Чтобы они отображались приходится запускать приложение вновь

MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnAddMA = findViewById(R.id.btn_add_MA);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.rv_list);

    dataBase = new DataBase(this);
    sqLiteDatabase = dataBase.getWritableDatabase();

    //переход на след активити и добавления в базу
    btnAddMA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    //вывод данных из базы
    cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(dataBase.DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    simpleCursorAdapter = new MySimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, cursor, 0);
    listView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    cursor.close();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Второе активити

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edtValues1SA;
    EditText edtValues2SA;
    Button btnAddValuesSA;
    DataBase dataBase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        edtValues1SA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_value_1_SA);
        edtValues2SA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_value_2_SA);
        btnAddValuesSA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add_values_SA);


        dataBase = new DataBase(this);
        final SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = dataBase.getWritableDatabase();
        final ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        btnAddValuesSA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String value1 = edtValues1SA.getText().toString();
                String value2 = edtValues2SA.getText().toString();
                contentValues.put(dataBase.KEY_TITLE, value1);
                contentValues.put(dataBase.KEY_TEXT, value2);

                sqLiteDatabase.insert(dataBase.DATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
                finish();

            }
        });


    }
}
```

CursorAdapter

```
public class MySimpleAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    DataBase dataBase;

    public MySimpleAdapter(Context context,Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context,  c,  flags);
    }


    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView tvTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_title_item_list);
        TextView tvTexte = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_text_item_list);

        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dataBase.KEY_TITLE));
        String text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dataBase.KEY_TEXT));

        tvTitle.setText(title);
        tvTexte.setText(text);

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: А с чего вы решили, что они должны обновляться? У вас `onCreate` срабатывает только при создании `Activity`, при возврате из второго `Activity` в первое, в нём не срабатывает `onCreate`. Учите жизненный цикл `Activity`.

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо каким-либо способом обновить данные из БД при возврате к активити. Само собой оно не обновится.

В реальном мире это делается обычно так:

1. Данные из БД берутся какой-либо библиотекой (Room, например). Получение данных завёрнуто в RxJava или LiveData, которые автоматически (если надо) перезапрашивают данные из БД, если что-то в БД поменялось (изменения отслеживают библиотеки (Room)).
2. Однако п.1 будет выполняться только если активити не уничтожена или запрос в БД изначальный делается из `onResume`, например, что, конечно, излишне.
3. Чтобы избежать вышеописанной проблемы используют архитектурные библиотеки для реализации MVP (MVVM etc). Тогда запрос в БД идёт в презентерах, которые нужным образом уже настроены на события жизненного цикла и корректно перезапрашивают данные в нужный момент.

---

Однако, в вашем случае, раз вы не используете ничего из вышеперечисленных библиотек и подходов, вам нужно всё сделать вручную. Например так:

1. Запускайте вторую активити через `startActivityForResult()`
2. Перед закрытие второй активити установите её результат через `setResult()`
3. При возвращении к первой активити вызовется её метод `onActivityResult()` - в нём сделайте повторый запрос к БД и обновите полученными данными список на экране.

Answer (score -1):

Я в MainActivity в методе onRestart повторно получаю данные из базы и вновь добавленная запись отображается сразу

```
 protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();

    cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(dataBase.DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    simpleCursorAdapter = new MySimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, cursor, 0);
    listView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);

}
```